# What is the correct way to use inline style in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to react and I was trying to figure out the correct way to use inline style in react

for Example this is something I am doing

```
import React from 'react';
import Classes from './toolbar.css';
import Logo from '../../logo/logo.js';
import Navitems from '../navigation-items/navigation-items.js';

const toolbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <header className={Classes.Toolbar}>
    <div> Menu </div>
    <Logo style={{height: "70%"}}/>
    <nav className={Classes.DesktopOnly}>
    <Navitems />
    </nav>
    </header>
  )

}

export default toolbar;
```

Here this doesn't seem to be working

```
 <Logo style={{height: "70%"}}/>
```

Any Guesses what would I be doing wrong?

Also, Logo have its own external CSS but I guess inline-Css should dominate over the external css?

Comment: If Logo, which you don't show us, doesn't assign `...props` or the style prop, then it won't be put on the element

Comment: It's not really inline CSS if it's on a component. Despite looking like an HTML element, `<Logo />` is actually a React component imported from a JS file, and therefore the inline styling doesn't work the same. Instead it sees 'style' as a prop that you can access from Logo.js within which `console.log(this.props.style)` will log `{height: "70%"}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an example of inline styling* from the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html):

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

If you want the object containing the style rules to live in the `style` attribute itself, the docs provide an example of that too.

```
// Result style: '10%'
<div style={{ height: '10%' }}>
  Hello World!
</div>
```

Note that in both examples, `style` is an attribute of a JSX tag, not of a user-defined component (like `<Logo/>`). If you try passing styles directly to a component, the object passed will live in that component's props (and be accessible in that component via `props.style`) but the styles contained therein won't be applied.

*Inline insofar as the style rules are embedded in the component's JSX file as opposed to an external stylesheet

Comment: Could you use color and backgroundImage in your inline style example to be consistent with the first example? I'd like to see how to add more than one style inline.